# Should I preallocate a numpy array?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, memory

I have a class and its method. The method repeats many times during execution. This method uses a `numpy` array as a temporary buffer. I don't need to store values inside the buffer between method calls. Should I create a member instance of the array to avoid time leaks on memory allocation during the method execution? I know that it is preferred to use local variables. But is Python smart enough to allocate memory for the array only once?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.temp = numpy.zeros(n)
    def method(self):
        # do some stuff using self.temp
```

Or

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def method(self):
        temp = numpy.zeros(self.n)
        # do some stuff using temp
```

Update: replaced `np.empty` with `np.zeros`

Comment: `np.empty` is a lazy allocator.  My guess is that you will need to try both ways and see if there is any time difference for sample actions.

Comment: When I use preallocation or local definition in different places, I see both increase and decrease of mean time. So, I can't distinguish what is better.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  Sometimes it is asking OS for more memory, other times it is reusing garbage collected space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to preallocate large arrays. But if this will be efficient depends on how you use these arrays then.

This  will cause  several new allocations for intermediate results of computation:

```
self.temp = a * b + c
```

This will not (if `self.x` is preallocated):

```
numpy.multiply(a, b, out=self.x)
numpy.add(c, self.x, out=self.temp)
```

But for these cases (when you work with large arrays in not-trivial formulae) it is better to use [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) or [einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for matrix calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy arrays are fast, once created. However, creating an array is pretty expensive. Much more than, say, creating a python list.

In a case such as yours, where you create a new array again and again (in a for loop?), I would ALWAYS pre-allocate the array structure and then reuse it.

I can't comment on whether Python is smart enough to optimize this, but I would guess it's not :)

How big is your array and how frequent are calls to this method?

Comment: The array is about 1000 float elements. Calls occur not very frequent, but if they do, they should be executed as fast as possible.

Comment: This is not a lot. Still - prepare your array inside `__init__` and have it ready. Also, might be a good idea to set its type properly, eg.`self.temp = numpy.zeros(n, dtype='float64')`.